# Does the allan variance function in Matlab (allanvar) use overlapped or non-overlapped calculation?

Tags: matlab, variance

Is the Matlab code available anywhere?

I'm trying to understand what exactly does it do. As I understood, it divides the data into segments with length tau (when tau increases each time) and then averages the data within each segment. After that, it compares the value attained from successive segments.

Am I correct in my understanding?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can view the code by typing `edit allanvar` into the command window.

Of course, this assumes you've already downloaded the associated toolbox.

Comment: It says this command is not available for a P-file.. so it seems it doesn't work this way

Comment: Not sure, it worked for me. You can also try typing ```which allanvar``` and then open the file in a text editor or something.

Comment: Thanks! I tried opening it in Notepad and it gives gibberish:
v01.00v00.00 @ה¿±  ֳ    U
׀Ma$ק¡¥ָe­M÷₪‏¹מV«¹ל˜†²qu0¼ֳד±t9Trs^x¦׳ „¢¬9j‰hֺF •‚¾״™&;„_™­nׂ@Sn<¥סm}א¯x_°k^
ײ¢£א"ֱK$‘׀ױfzRג¢”ׁ8‚¿‏״;‚י©qcׂ׃1[3ץFExjx‰{F(ַH¬א2<G*₪"ל×Kl›.$L¢ֵׂ:eI»Lׁ5-טQ~ֽ—(^w”# j~טֵ;U1³מp#»®t¦bרFeC­׀`¿Vcם•ּתw‡÷¿ל_C•“ִ6u”ת™`X<רױKשˆ‡‡©2r³ֹ׳ה‡9dה©‚עi¾Aֹ


Is there any chance you can copy and send the code?

Comment: If you've found the file then just open it in matlab. Usually you can do this easily by simply dragging the file into the MATLAB editor window (above the command window).

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same approach, but was also UNable to open the allanvar.p file. Despite the documentation I've found, if I use simple white noise and run allanvar on it, when I plot sqrt(this output), I get a line with a slope of -1/2 on a log-log scale (one order of magnitude drop in ADEV for two orders of magnitude increase in averaging interval value). A simple program to compute the OVERLAPPING Allan variance yields a -1/1 slope. Thus I am suspicious that the allanvar function does not compute the overlapping version!